# Partition By use and splitting the value to create multiple rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named **Test1** as following :

```
A         B                C
One     ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL    4
Two     AAA,GGG,RTG        3
Three   A,B,C,D            4
One                        0
Two     TE,YT              2
```

I want output like following :

```
A     B      C
One   ABC     6
One   DEF     6
One   GHI     6
One   JKL     6
One           6
Three   A     4
Three   B     4
Three   C     4
Three   D     4
Two           7
Two     AAA   7
Two     GGG   7
Two     RTG   7
```

I tried following query but i am getting problem in output with partition by.

```
SELECT A,SUM(C) OVER (PARTITION BY A),left(d, charindex(',', d + ',')-1) as "B" from 
            (SELECT *, substring(B, number, 3000) as d from Test1 A left join
             (SELECT distinct number from master.dbo.spt_values where number between 1 and 200) B
              on substring(',' + B, number, 1) = ',') t
```

Using above i get following :

```
A     C     B
One   18    ABC
One   18    DEF
One   18    GHI
One   18    JKL
One   18    
Three 16    A
Three 16    B
Three 16    C
Three 16    D
Two   13    
Two   13    AAA
Two   13    GGG
Two   13    RTG
```

I am trying to create rows for multiple entries in column B seperated with comma and also adding the C column value according to the group. 
Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: You want `SUM(1) OVER (PARTITION BY A)`, not `SUM(C)`. Alternatively, `COUNT(*) OVER...` instead of `SUM(1) OVER...`.

Comment: I tried it but it is not working :|

Answer (score 0):

Just look for a `split()` function on the web (you'll get a bunch of hits by googling "sql server split").

Then you can do something like:

```
select t.a, t.c, s.b
from test t outer apply
     dbo.split(t.b) as s(b);
```

There are other methods too . . . using XML or using a recursive CTE.